# How to convert an ArrayList to JSON not working

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert to convert an `ArrayList<String>` to JSON object. The problem is that I'm getting all the same values everywhere.

Here is my code:

```
Location l = new Location((long) 1,"u222","fdfgs","morococ","2dqrg","8drgf5","8dfg");
        Location l2 = new Location((long) 1,"u222","fedsfsds","modfrococ","27","876gtfgfg85","8 25 98");
        Location l3 = new Location((long) 1,"u222","fes","morococ","27","876fghfgh85","8 25 98");

        List<Location> locs = new ArrayList<Location>();;
        locs.add(l);
        locs.add(l2);
        locs.add(l3);
        
        List<JsonValid> jsons = new ArrayList<JsonValid>();
        JsonValid jsonV = new JsonValid();

         //copying to another list to a valid format of json
        for(int i = 0 ; i<locs.size();i++)
        {
            jsonV.title = locs.get(i).city;
            jsonV.lat = locs.get(i).latitude;
            jsonV.lng = locs.get(i).longitude;
            
            jsons.add(jsonV);
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(jsons.size());
        
        gson = new Gson();
        String jsonStudents = gson.toJson(jsons);
        //Here i'm getting the same values 
        System.out.println(jsonStudents);
```

Here is the output:

```
[{"title":"fes","lat":"27","lng":"876fghfgh85","description":"none"},{"title":"fes","lat":"27","lng":"876fghfgh85","description":"none"},{"title":"fes","lat":"27","lng":"876fghfgh85","description":"none"}]
```

Which is not what I want! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your loop - you're re-using `jsonV` each time.

Try moving the `jsonV` declaration to your loop:

```
//copying to another list to a valid format of json
for(int i = 0 ; i<locs.size();i++)
{
    JsonValid jsonV = new JsonValid();
    // ...
}
```